# have taken VS took

Tags: past-tense

I have to write one of the following phrases into a text message

> 1. I want to see all the photos that you have taken during your trip
> 2. I want to see all the photos that you took during your trip

Should I use past perfect or simple past ?

Comment: When is this being said? During the trip or after it?

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the context.

The rule is that you cannot use present perfect with a time expression which does not include the 'present', the time when you speak or write.

Consequently, if you are asking about pictures taken during a trip which is finished, you cannot use the present perfect with *during your trip*, because that defines a timespan which lies entirely in the past. You must use the simple past.

On the other hand, if you are asking about pictures taken during a trip which is still going on—for instance, you meet someone who is visiting your, town or you text someone from your town who is still away, and ask about the trip which is in progress—you *should* use the present perfect and avoid the simple past: the past isn't ungrammatical, but it implies that your visitor is done taking pictures.

Comment: Stop typing so fast.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I don't need no stinkin Dvorak.

Comment: I suspect hyperdactyly whatever the keyboard.